GCP Logging: who created a Project?
I'm trying to find Project creation events in GCP, but the query I'm using doesn't return any results:
protoPayload.methodName="google.cloudresourcemanager.v1.ProjectService.CreateProject"
resource.type="project"

I tried searching both in Organization scope and in a Folder scope and neither returns any results. I am filtering by the last 400 days to make sure that I'm searching all the retained logs.

The methodName should be CreateProject. The serviceName is cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com

Are you sure the project has been created the past 400 days?

@guillaumeblaquiere yes, I'm sure

@DazWilkin can you add an answer with the contents of your comment so that I can mark it as accepted?

protoPayload.methodName should be CreateProject.
protoPayload.serviceName is cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com
